# PNG images are not rendered with transparency

Tags: bug, old-teams

I'm not sure if this is actually a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) or intended behavior so I'll just assume it's a bug until told otherwise.

We uploaded a 300x300 PNG of our logo. The PNG had an alpha channel which seems to have been lost when the image was rescaled:

[image]

Is this intentional? If so, you may want to update the "Create Team" form to mention that alpha channels will be ignored:

[image]

Comment: This is an Imgur artifact - we'll take a look and see what the behavior *should* be. It's an consequence of the resize on their side.

Comment: I'll upload an image with a white background in the meantime.

Comment: @NickCraver: Presumably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210132/new-top-bar-should-render-avatar-with-a-transparent-background

Comment: If I understand correctly, the image is uploaded to imgur servers through Stack Exchange. Perhaps they (Stack Exchange) could do the resizing on their end before pushing it to imgur.